# Calculate the volume of the body formed by the rotation of the figure

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, volume

I need to calculate the volume of a body formed by rotating a figure bounded by curves $y=0$, $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and $y=\sqrt{\frac32}x$ around the $Ox$ axis.

The graph of the function and the required volume:

[image]

I built a graph and I know the formula, but I can’t figure out which limits to take and what volume to take and subtract from the other in order to get the right answer.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thanks, mate, it's really help me

Comment: Then why didn't you edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only working with area above the $x$ axis I'd change the function to $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.  Then find what $x$ value the functions intersect at, integrate $\sqrt{1 -x^2} - 1.5x$ from $0$ to that number and apply it to the disk method formula, then just integrate $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ from that number to $1$ and apply it to the disk method formula.